# How can I create full calendar visual force page in sales force?

Tags: salesforce

How can I create a full calendar that works the same like the standard calendar?

I used this link for that:
http://www.codebycody.com/2013/06/create-calendar-view-in-salesforcecom.html
but this doesn't showing me events on vf page.

Comment: Post what you have tried so far. It is impossible for someone to help if don't show what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked a the free [AnyCalendar](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000Ev8qpUAB) Lightning Component on the AppExchange.  It uses the Full Calendar js library.  You could just embed that in a Visualforce page.  That would allow you to easily upgrade when you eventually migrate to lightning.